# Dialogflow language coverage and Google Neural Machine Translation

Tags: google-translate, dialogflow-es, api-ai

Google started “Google Neural Machine Translation” system in 2016 and improved the efficiency of translation of some languages tremendously. These languages include German, French, Spanish, Portuguese, Chinese, Japanese, Turkish and Korean; as they said.

However Dialogflow supports all of these languages except Turkish. Is there any specific reason for this exclusion?

Answer (score 0):

Dialogflow does not handle translation, so Google's work in this area doesn't apply.

What Dialogflow *does* do that is language related is let you create sample phrases, in that language, and can handle other, similar, phrases that a user might make in conversation. So it isn't about translating a language - it is about natural language parsing and understanding.